# Creating unique scales for parallel coordinates using d3 (multivariate)

Tags: d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I'm trying to find a way to assign different scale max/min to different columns of my data using parallel coordinates. I've adopted code from http://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281 but **do not want** to use d3.extent. I've tried different methods (for loops, if statements) but d3 doesn't seem to like that.

Any ideas for how I should approach this?

```
 d3.json("HW3/scores.json", function(error, scores){
  x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(scores[0]).filter(function(d){
    return d != "Country" && (y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(d3.extent(scores, function(p) { return +p[d]; }))
        .range([height, 0]));
  }));
```

I'm trying to change the domains of 6 scales (pulled from scores.json, all numbers in column format) to be unique to the data type:

- percent (columns 1 and 6) should be from 1 - 100,
- score (columns 3 and 4) should be from 200 - max of both score
  columns,
- hours (columns 2 and 5) should be from 0 - max of both hour columns.

Please and Thank You for ANY help you can provide to a d3 n00b.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the code that creates the scales from the filter function and create the y scales manually according to your specification:

```
x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(d) {
  return d != "name";
}));

y['percent 1'] = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([1, 100])
    .range([height, 0]));
y['hours 1'] = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(p) { return Math.max(+p['hours 1'], +p['hours 2']); }])
    .range([height, 0]));
// etc
```

Comment: thanks for the post. I tried this, and while console did not show any errors, the scales would not render. I tried doing one at a time as well, and no luck. Thanks anyways though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example of what you're trying to do that demonstrates the problem please?